# ROM Toolbox Pro crashes after deleting some of the downloaded boot animation

Tags: applications, root-access

I'm using rooted Sony Xperia P on Android 4.1.2. I used the ROM Toolbox Pro app to change my stock font and boot animation. It ran so perfectly then. Then I deleted some of the boot animation downloaded by that app (those animations which I downloaded and previewed) but I kept my stock animation and the one I used. I didn't delete anything else. Then I opened the app and it crashed with the message 'Unfortunately, ROM Toolbox Pro has stopped'.

I wiped the cache & data, but it still didn't run. I also reinstalled it, but still, it didn't work. So, I wiped the Dalvik cache of this app only, but still no change.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these:

- Install catlog or any other logger
- Set on error
- Install ROM Toolbox Pro and run.
- Open catlog and save. It should contain the errors.
- Post here.

After that.

- Delete its data folder in `/data/data/` (something like `com.jrummy.[...]`).
- Uninstall.
- Rename and move its folder found on your SD card (`romtoolbox`) somewhere else.
- Install a previous version
- Try again
- If not, uninstall and try ROM Toolbox Lite
- Let the developer know about it. Include the log